ng-class does not update on variable change using tailwindcss styles
I use Angular 18 and TailwindCSS. I wanted to create a cool typing animation with different colors per word. However, when currentColor updates to the next tailwind color, it does not show the proper color but only black text. Is there a possibility to fix that using tailwind colors?
I have the following code:
<span class="relative">
   <span [ngClass]="currentColor">{{ displayText }}</span>
</span>

 keywords = ['Java', 'AngularJS', 'Typescript'];
  colors = ['text-red-500', 'text-blue-500', 'text-green-500'];
  currentWordIndex = 0;
  displayText = '';
  isDeleting = false;
  typingSpeed = 150;
  deletingSpeed = 100;
  currentColor = this.colors[0];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.startTyping();
  }

  startTyping() {
    const currentWord = this.keywords[this.currentWordIndex];
    const currentLength = this.displayText.length;

    if (this.isDeleting) {
      this.displayText = currentWord.substring(0, currentLength - 1);
      if (this.displayText === '') {
        this.isDeleting = false;
        this.currentWordIndex = (this.currentWordIndex + 1) % this.keywords.length;
        this.currentColor = this.colors[this.currentWordIndex];
        console.log(this.currentColor);
      }
    } else {
      this.displayText = currentWord.substring(0, currentLength + 1);
      if (this.displayText === currentWord) {
        this.isDeleting = true;
      }
    }

Tailwind config:
module.exports = {
  darkMode: 'selector',
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}", "./node_modules/tw-elements/js/**/*.js", "./node_modules/flowbite/**/*.js"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      scale: {
        '101': '1.01',
        '102': '1.02',
      },
      boxShadow: {
        'btn-1': '0 1px 0 rgba(27,31,35,0.1)'
      },
      colors: {
        'dark-mode': '#050505',
        'dark-mode-inside': '#1f2937',
        'dark-mode-inside-hover': '#2a3748',
        'title-dark-mode-text': '#eaeaea',
        'dark-mode-text': '#909090',
        'dark-mode-text-hover': '#787878'
      },
      keyframes: {
        fadeInDown: {
          '0%': {opacity: '0', transform: 'translateY(-20px)'},
          '100%': {opacity: '1', transform: 'translateY(0)'},
        },
        fadeInUp: {
          '0%': {opacity: '0', transform: 'translateY(20px)'},
          '100%': {opacity: '1', transform: 'translateY(0)'},
        },
        fadeInRight: {
          '0%': {opacity: '0', transform: 'translateX(-20px)'},
          '100%': {opacity: '1', transform: 'translateX(0)'},
        },
        fadeInLeft: {
          '0%': {opacity: '0', transform: 'translateX(20px)'},
          '100%': {opacity: '1', transform: 'translateX(0)'},
        },
        fadeInSlow: {
          '0%': {opacity: '0'},
          '100%': {opacity: '1'},
        },
      },
      animation: {
        fadeInDown: 'fadeInDown 0.5s ease-out forwards',
        fadeInUp: 'fadeInUp 0.5s ease-out forwards',
        fadeInRight: 'fadeInRight 0.5s ease-out forwards',
        fadeInLeft: 'fadeInLeft 0.5s ease-out forwards',
        fadeInSlow: 'fadeInSlow 0.5s ease-out forwards',
        fadeIn: 'fadeIn 0.5s ease-out forwards',
        bounce: 'bounce 1.5s infinite',
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    require('flowbite/plugin'),
    require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
  ],
}



When i try to preload the colors using e.g. class="text-green-500", the proper color will be shown in my typing animation after class="text-green-500" is removed.
I also tested it with class="{{currentColor}} but it does not work. When using css style classes instead of tailwind, it works

Why don't you use ngClass?

Updated the code - Also tested it with both but does not work

can you provide your tailwind.config.js file please

does it work if you manually edit the html element and apply 'text-red-500' class to to it? Maybe you're missing the CSS code for those classes?

@T.Jami updated my post!

@Shahar if i manually add text-red-500 everything works fine. See my last paragraph what i have tried

Your configuration is not adjusted for Angular.
Since in Angular you are using typescript files, instead of javascript. You are supposed to add the .ts extension to your configuration. Currently you got only html and js. This explains why the classes work if you add them into your component.html file but not if you declare the values in the component.ts.
Here is how the configuration should look like for Angular, based on Tailwind-Css Docs.
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{html,ts}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}

